# Daemon call to Microsoft Graph with Microsoft.Identity vs Azure.Identity

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api

Is there a problem or disadvantage to using Azure.Identity instead of Microsoft.Identity.Client or Microsoft.Identity.Web to call Microsoft Graph?

I'm trying to do asp.net core 3.1 MVC webapp to access a calendar list on sharepoint without having a user to signin.

I got the app registered in Azure with application permission Sites.Selected and did the admin post thing to get read access to the specific site...

I've found this console example which works fine:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2/tree/master/1-Call-MSGraph
It uses Microsoft.Identity.Client and there's a bit of code..

I kept on looking for other ways and found some examples using Microsoft.Identity.Web which I only tested for delegated but I assume it could work without a user signin.

Then I found an example using Azure.Identity and it works with very little code...

```
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);

GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential);

var result = graphServiceClient.Sites[siteId]
                .Lists[listId]
                .Items
                .Request(queryOptions)
                .GetAsync().Result;
```

(queryOptions is just expand select filter orderby to get the specific info I'm looking for)

It just seems too easy.. There has to be something wrong doing it this way?

Comment: I think its fine as well. Nothing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing to worry about. In fact, you should prefer using the Azure.Identity package because it is newer. With the new package, it is easier for developers to generate access tokens. Under the hood Microsoft still uses the ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder, which you can check yourself by inspecting the [source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/identity/Azure.Identity/src/ClientSecretCredential.cs) and drilling down into the class [MSALConfidentialClient](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/identity/Azure.Identity/src/MsalConfidentialClient.cs). Basically, the complexity has not changed, but is now managed by Microsoft.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Apparently, I can't upvote since I'm new